# Arnold’s definition of integral curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Arnold, in his *Ordinary Differential Equations*, defines:

> A line that, at each of its points, is tangent to a vector field is called an integral curve of the direction field.

**Question:** Why is he not being general and replacing vector field with direction field?

Comment: I think this is because he wants to think the curve as its image. Taking only directions enables to forget about parametrization.

Comment: @Alexandre Whose image?

Comment: @Alexandre the curve’s image

Comment: @R.Alexandre Under what operation?

Comment: @Alexandre : well, you know that starting from a vector field, you can take the curve that resolves the EDO. Know forget about the non-directional information of the vector field and you get a curve (more specifically its image) that is geometrically tangent of the direction field

Comment: My bad! I didn't ask properly. I am asking why he is *not* using direction field instead of vector field.

Comment: To me it is not super clear that a direction field suffices to resolve the EDO-type problem of integrating (existence and uniqueness). It seems that this is still true but it requires some work. Maybe that is a good reason.

Comment: There is context missing. If the text discussed vector fields previously, then it is natural to refer to vector fields. If it were discussing differential forms and exact DE previously, then one would refer to the corresponding line bundle or direction field.